# Excel data taken as Json to convert in Table using AngularJs... No output is coming

Tags: javascript, angularjs

--- AngularJs File--------

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope){

$scope.exceldata=[];

var excelJsonObj=[];

$scope.uploadExcelFile = function(){

var myFile = document.getElementById('file');

var input = myFile;

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){

var fileData = reader.result;

var workbook = XLSX.read(fileData, {type: 'binary'});

workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName){

var rowObject = 
XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);

excelJsonObj = rowObject;

});

$scope.exceldata = excelJsonObj;

console.log($scope.exceldata);

};

reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);

};

});
```

------html-------

```
    <div>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadExcelFile()">
        </form>
    </div><br><br>
    <div>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Keyword</th>
                <th>Package</th>
                <th>Data1</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in exceldata">
                <td>{{data.Keyword}}</td>
                <td>{{data.Package}}</td>
                <td>{{data.Data1}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: what is the output of {{data}} ? post your entire html please

Comment: $scope.exceldata is of array type. And you are trying to assing an object to you, which is wrong. you should use "push" function for adding new elements to an array

Comment: Ya.. I'm not getting error but when I was taking excelsheet data and trying to display as a table using ng-repeat, it's not working. It displays nothing